# SSRS Reports using parameters fill blank space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

In SSRS, when you access a report that has a parameter requirement, you are presented with a similar screen to my attached image.

Is there anyway to place an image or some text in the huge empty space that is available before you select you parameters and click View Report.

For example I need to write some instructions on the rules of selecting a start date and end date (i.e start date must be a monday and end date must be a sunday) and it would also be nice to place an image such as company logo to fill that space.

I feel it ruins the look of the report when the link is clicked and you are presented with a blank page at first glance.

Has anyone got any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: The short answer to this is no, you'd have to change the entire .css file that is used and it would affect all reports.  Force the user to select valid mondays to valid sundays.  This could be auto temp table that populates with mondays for the current year, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can think of may be more of a workaround than a solution, but here goes:

You could make the parameters optional (NULLable). You could have the report consist of two containers (e.g. rectangles) and switch visibility based on if the parameters are set or not. The first container has the instructions, the second the content. You may have to configure your data sets in such a way that there will be no problems there (no big result sets if the params are NULL, for example).